# How to sync the Stack building order *Not the Z-order

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, stack, rendering, building

Description:

I have a Stack with two Widgets. Widget1 (as a background) being a Grid of 4 AssetImages and Widget2 being a semi-transparent rectangular coloured Container building on top of Widget1. The Stack is building both widgets as expected!

Problem:

Widget2 is visually rendered before Widget1, which leads to an awkward effect because Widget2 is rendered over an empty background. I assume that this is caused by Stack async building of children however AssetImage is a synchronous call...

Question:

How to make Widget2 rendering to wait for widget1 until Widget1 gets fully visual as the background?

Notice that I have already tried WidgetBindings.instance.addPostframeCallback

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

I think there is no need to wait for `widget1`. You can pre-cache the `widget1` and `widget2` assets with [`precacheImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) way before displaying them. This way they're going to show almost immediately.

```dart
await precacheImage(AssetImage('assets/widget1.png'), context);
await precacheImage(AssetImage('assets/widget2.png'), context);
```

From the docs, after the call of `precacheImage`:

> If the image is later used by an `Image` or `BoxDecoration` or `FadeInImage`, it will probably be loaded faster. The consumer of the image does not need to use the same ImageProvider instance. The ImageCache will find the image as long as both images share the same key, and the image is held by the cache.

### Solution 2

Otherwise, you can use [`Future.delayed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) to wait a bit for the `widget1` to get rendered. The call to `delayed` should [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) of some flag that builds the `widget2`, let's say `bool _buildWidget2 = false` flag. Something like the below code snippet:

```dart
Future.delayed(
  Duration(milliseconds: 150),
  () => setState(() => _buildWidget2 = true),
);
```

And then on the `Stack` it should be something:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Widget1(),
    if (_buildWidget2)
      Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer...testing which approach better for me

Answer (score 0):

If it is me, use a timer to call widget2 late (process animation)

Or I guess I'll just use imageProvider.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer...testing which approach better for me